# Write array to xml Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, xml

I need to generate simple file with test results with the next fields:

```
Total N
Pass N
Fail N

Failed: testName1
...
Failed: testNameN
```

I use Nokogiri to write xml file.
For first 3 fields I have the next code:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml| 
xml.body do
    xml.Total total
    xml.Pass pass
    xml.Fail fail
    end
}.to_xml
```

I have array with failed test names. And I need iterate thought that array and write each failed test name to this xml file, using nokogiri. How is to do that?
I want something like this:

```
<failed> testname1 </failed>
<failed> testname2 </failed>
<failed> testnameN </failed>
```

Comment: what is the problem with your current solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few notes :

`fail` is a synonym for `raise`, and shouldn't be used as a variable name.

It might cause confusion if you use `xml` for both the String from your Nokogiri::XML::Builder and for the bound variable used inside the Builder block.

```
require 'nokogiri'

total = 5
pass_count = 3
fail_count = 2

failed_tests = ["test_name_1", "test_name_3"]

xml_content = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml| 
  xml.body do
    xml.Total total
    xml.Pass pass_count
    xml.Fail fail_count

    xml.failed do
      failed_tests.each do |failed_test|
        xml.failed failed_test
      end
    end

  end
}.to_xml

puts xml_content

# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <body>
#  <Total>5</Total>
#  <Pass>3</Pass>
#  <Fail>2</Fail>
#  <failed>
#    <failed>test_name_1</failed>
#    <failed>test_name_3</failed>
#  </failed>
# </body>
```

Comment: How setup encoding of xml in my xml initialization ?